# Non-shared inventories in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have an ansible repository with multiple inventories (everything is very standard). Something like:

```
- inventories/
   - inv1
   - inv2
   ...
   - invN
- roles/
- playbooks/
```

I have multiple deploy servers from which I can run ansible. There is a restriction: deploy server should have only those inventories (i think I will always have relation 1-to-1) which it will use. It means, that if server `srv1` uses inv1 the rest of inventories should not present.

I was thinking about two approaches:

- each inventory goes to separated git repo and I will checkout only selected repositories;
- almost the same as previous but instead of multiple branches in a single git repo.

Both these solutions seems to be a kind of dirty hack and I believe that there is more simple and elegant solution (however I did not find anything in ansible guidelines). Any suggestions?

Thank you

CLARIFICATION ADDED:
As far as I see I did not formulated my question clearly.
The question is more about that on deployment server I should not have more than N (most likely 1) inventory **physically**.
Shown above structure show my current git repo but on the deployment server I should have something like:

```
deployment_server1:
- inventories/
   - inv1/
- roles/
- ....

deployment_server2:
- inventories/
    -inv87/
- roles/
- playbooks/

... and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use the [`ansible.cfg`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html) file to point to inventory.

```
[defaults]
inventory = hosts
host_key_checking = False
```

Or you can change the running inventory as
`ansible-playbook example.yml -i inventory`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're running ansible on these hosts, it might be worth remembering that you can override any setting in ansible with an environment variable. ANSIBLE_INVENTORY is all you need here.

ANSIBLE_INVENTORY=$(hostname) ansible [args] for example, would use an inventory file with the same name as the current host.

You can also override it with the -i flag.

Comment: thanks for you reply. I added some clarifications to my question

Comment: Hrm, I don't know then. There are kind of red flags here. I mean if you're trying to not put the inventory files on the servers because they contain sensitive security information, you probably want another solution? Are you deploying by just doing git pull on each server?

Comment: rsync might be a simple-ish solution. rsync --exclude=inventories/* --include/inventories/the-file-you-want would get you where you want to be, but feels kind of hackish in a bad way.

Comment: Also (I kind of hate that comments are just one line) you might want to ask this as something other than an ansible question, it doesn't really seem ansible specific.